# Odd camera roll effect in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

So I was working on a custom camera controller for a first person unity game. When I individually test pitch and yaw the camera controls perfectly. However, when I tested it with both pitch and yaw enabled I get a strange roll effect. I have no idea what causes this. Here's my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    CursorLockMode wantedMode;
    public float xSense = 20.0f, ySense = 20.0f;

    void SetCursorLockState(){

        Cursor.lockState = wantedMode;
        Cursor.visible = (CursorLockMode.Locked != wantedMode);
    }

    void Start(){

        wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        SetCursorLockState();
    }

    void Update() {

        transform.Rotate(-(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySense), (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")) * xSense, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think because you apply the first transform then the other it is in essence behaving as if you did the one maneuver then the next.. you need to apply them together based on the original position of your object. (aka multiply both transforms together and apply them together or something.. its been a while)

Comment: This reduced the complexity of my code, but it didn't fix the issue. At least my code is now readable and not as over complicated.

Comment: Sorry its been a long time since I played with transforms.. I found this read that may be relevant (especially one that talks about pitch and yaw on empty objects) https://answers.unity.com/questions/375589/how-to-rotate-two-axes-independently-simultaneousl.html